# how to determine the application exit event

Tags: applescript

I created a app by script editor ,using applescript . In the code , i used  "repeat ... end repeat"  to mock a timer . When the code was compiled,  i ran the app . it worked fine , but ,if i right click the app icon ,and chose menu "Quit" , nothing happen.
I know i should do a "EXIT" checking , but , i don't know how to do that.
Anybody can help?

```
on main()

    set f1 to "/System/Library/Sounds/Pop.aiff"
    set f2 to "/System/Library/Sounds/Ping.aiff"
    set f3 to "/System/Library/Sounds/Glass.aiff"
    set f4 to "/System/Library/Sounds/Tink.aiff"

    repeat
        set now to current date
        set h to hours of now
        set m to minutes of now
        set s to seconds of now

        if (h = 6) and (m = 30) and (s = 0) then 
                --some code here
        end if

        delay 0.5

    end repeat

end main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repeat loop blocks the code.

As the code is saved as application use the on idle handler which is called periodically depending on the return value.

```
global f1, f2, f3, f4

on run
    set f1 to "/System/Library/Sounds/Pop.aiff"
    set f2 to "/System/Library/Sounds/Ping.aiff"
    set f3 to "/System/Library/Sounds/Glass.aiff"
    set f4 to "/System/Library/Sounds/Tink.aiff"
end run

on idle   
    set {hours:h, minutes:m, seconds:s} to current date
    if (h = 6) and (m = 30) and (s = 0) then 
            --some code here
    end if
    return 1
end idle
```